# Can human be emotionless?

Tags: brain, endocrinology, neurotransmitter

Is it possible that a person can't produce, like, dopamine, serotonin, and other emotion hormones? Or, a part of the brain can't function to make one feel something?

Comment: There are diseases, which are linked to suppressed hormone production or loss of the specific receptor. But completely emotionless? I don't think so, as this would mean, that all hormones or receptors are affected.

Comment: Yes Schizophrenia  is a disorder in which one suffers from lack of emotion and motivation.They are called negative symptoms.You can google it out

Comment: @SanjuktaGhose Even with negative schizophrenia symptoms, there is certainly not a complete lack of emotion, that doesn't seem to be the OPs question.